# c# editorconfig CA1062 null check validation methods (for guard clauses) with nullable reference types

Tags: c#, code-analysis, editorconfig, nullable-reference-types

I have created a small `dotnetstandard 2.1` library project in a solution.  I want to test out using [Nullable Reference Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references).  As part of this, I want to have appropriate compilation errors and warnings.

TLDR;
I want to know how to setup the CA1062 code quality settings in `.editorconfig` correctly.

### Library Project

I have added the following `nuget` packages to the project:

```
<ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers" Version="2.9.8">
          <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
          <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      </PackageReference>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers" Version="2.9.8">
          <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
          <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      </PackageReference>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" Version="4.7.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Ardalis.GuardClauses" Version="1.4.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

This includes the various code analysis packages and also Steve Smith's nice [Guard Clauses](https://github.com/ardalis/GuardClauses) library.

Nullable Reference Types has been enabled using `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` in the project.

And I have a class which in the real world would be a nice implementation that actually did something:

```
using System;
using MyGuards;

namespace EditorConfigIssues
{
    public static class TestEditorConfig
    {
        public static void TestMethod(MyParam input)
        {
            string x = input.Check;
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
    }

    public class MyParam
    {
        public MyParam(string check) => Check = check;

        public string Check { get; }
    }
}
```

### Guard Library Project

In the solution I have added a simple Guard library which is another `dotnetstandard 2.1` project.

```
using System;

namespace MyGuards
{
    public static class FakeGuard
    {
        public static void Validate(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: This is not in competition of the GuardClauses library - just using to contrast editorconfig with!

### .editorconfig

I have added an `.editorconfig` to the root of solution with the following diagnostic checks:

```
dotnet_diagnostic.CA1062.severity = error
dotnet_code_quality.CA1062.exclude_extension_method_this_parameter = true
```

So with this in place, when I compile I get the following:
[image: Errors]

So everything is as I expect so far.  I am not using any guards yet.

### Fixing it up - Steve Smith's Guard Library

So lets try and implement the guard clauses from Steve Smiths Guard Library to get rid of the error.

So we add the following to `TestEditorConfig.TestMethod`:

```
Guard.Against.Null(input, nameof(input));
```

and tweak the `.editorconfig` with:

```
dotnet_code_quality.CA1062.null_check_validation_methods = Ardalis.GuardClauses.Guard.Against.Null
```

Excellent, all is good.  The error has disappeared.
[image: Initial error gone]

### Fixing it up - my own guard library

But now I want to use my own guard.  So we replace the initial guard check in `TestEditorConfig.TestMethod` with:

```
FakeGuard.Validate(input);
```

and replace the null_check_validation_methods in `.editorconfig` with:

```
dotnet_code_quality.CA1062.null_check_validation_methods = FakeGuard.Validate
```

The error is now back.
[image]

### Question(s)

1. The question is, what do I need in order to use a project with guards from the same solution?
2. Why am I getting warnings for the other CA1062 in the Error Window?

```
The keyword "dotnet_code_quality.CA1062.exclude_extension_method_this_parameter" is unknown
The keyword "dotnet_code_quality.CA1062.null_check_validation_methods" is unknown
```

I have been checking out this link [MS Docs Code Quality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1062?view=vs-2019) and tried various combinations for the FakeGuard, including:

- MyGuards
- MyGuards.FakeGuard
- FakeGuard
- MyGuards.FakeGuard.Validate
- FakeGuard.Validate
- Validate

Curiously, in a different solution, then I don't get any complaints about the CA1062 editorconfig settings in the Error Window.  And in there I have been unable to get the `null_check_validation_methods` working - hence putting together this solution.  This has been bugging me for a month or two, but finally getting the energy to put things together at the moment.

### EditorConfig Bug?

If I copy the FakeGuard file to the Library project, then the error message disappears.  But why does this not work in a different project in the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK... I posted on the `roslyn-analyzers` issues - here - https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/3451

As it turns out this is a bug.  For now here is the suggested workaround:

```
using System;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter)] 
internal sealed class ValidatedNotNullAttribute : Attribute { } 

namespace MyGuards
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Checks stuff.
    /// </summary>
    public static class FakeGuard
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// No more nulls.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj"></param>
        public static void Validate([ValidatedNotNull] object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }
    }
}
```