# Using c# Nullable Reference Type annotations from different assembly

Tags: c#, .net-5, nullable-reference-types

I created a null guard using the c# 8 "Nullable Reference Types" [feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) .

I placed it in a `Common` assembly, and call it from the `App` assembly. Both assemblies have `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>`.

My `.editorconfig` has `dotnet_diagnostic.CA1062.severity = warning`.

In the `Common` assembly, `Common/Guard.cs`:

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
namespace Common {
  public static class Guard {

    public static void IsNotNull([NotNull] object? arg, string? argName) =>
      _ = arg ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(argName);

  }
}
```

In the app assembly, `App/Printer.cs`:

```cs
using System;
using Common;
namespace App {
  public class Printer {

    public void PrintUpper(string text) {
      Guard.IsNotNull(text, nameof(text));
      Console.WriteLine(text.ToUpper());   // <--- CA1062
    }

    // it works when inside the same assembly:
    //public static void IsNotNull([NotNull] object? arg, string? argName) =>
    //  _ = arg ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(argName);

  }
}
```

Despite the null check and the `[NotNull]` annotation, I still get the `CA1062` warning. Interestingly, the warning disappears if I move the function into the same assembly.

I thought the NRT feature works across assemblies. What am I doing / understanding wrong?

Comment: You could use the [null-forgiving operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving) to supress the warning, e.g. `Console.WriteLine(text!.ToUpper());`

Comment: @ChrisPickford True. But I thought what I've done should work as is? Does the NRT feature not work across assemblies?

Comment: The only difference I can see between your code and [Postconditions: MaybeNull and NotNull](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis#postconditions-maybenull-and-notnull), is that they've marked the string parameter as nullable, i.e. `public void PrintUpper(string? text) {`. Maybe try that?

Comment: @ChrisPickford Thanks, yeah I saw that too :-) Unfortunately that doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this is [a](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60875814/9971404) [bug](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/3451#issuecomment-606690452), in roslyn's support for editorconfig.

My editorconfig had this:

```
dotnet_diagnostic.CA1062.severity = warning
```

**So actually it's not a c# NRT problem.**

The workaround is:

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter)]
internal sealed class ValidatedNotNullAttribute : Attribute { }

namespace Common {
  public static class Guard {

    public static void IsNotNull([ValidatedNotNull][NotNull] object? arg, string? argName) =>
      _ = arg ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(argName);

  }
}
```

And in `.editorconfig`:

```
dotnet_diagnostic.CA1062.severity = warning
dotnet_code_quality.CA1062.null_check_validation_methods = Guard.IsNotNull
```

I assume once the bug is resolved, I can remove all that and it would "just work" due to NRT.